# Formatting output of tree contents - Preorder traversal

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, tree, preorder

I have a method to print the contents of a tree:

```
void RedBlackTree::printPreorder(RedBlackNode *root){
    if(root == NULL) 
        return;
    cout << root->data << endl;
    printInorder(root->left);
    printInorder(root->right);
}
```

The contents of my tree are reading out correctly, but I want to format the tree so that it looks nicer. Right now, for a tree:

```
    c
   / \
  b   k
 /   / \
a   d   m
```

The contents print:

```
c
b
a
k
d
m
```

But I'd like to add some indentation, so that it reads:

```
c
    b
        a
    k
        d
        m
```

The format would be:

```
Root
    Left 
        LeftLeft
        LeftRight
    Right
        RightLeft
        RightRight

etc....
```

I'm just getting a bit lost with the recursion. Thanks!

Comment: you can pass a `depth` variable that increment at each call and print number of spaces equals to `depth`. See this example it print directory [printdir.c](http://www.johnloomis.org/ece537/notes/Files/Examples/printdir.html) ..you need to do something this in `c++`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void RedBlackTree::printPreorder(RedBlackNode *root, int depth){
    if(root == NULL) 
        return;
    for(int i=0; i<=depth; i++)
      cout <<" ";

    depth++;
    cout << root->data << endl;
    printInorder(root->left, depth);
    printInorder(root->right, depth);
}
```

Give it a try!!

Comment: welcome!!...have a look to `printdic.c` ...because better solution is possible. there must some `%*s` equivalent in `c++`.